# URL has too many redirects. Facebook won't be able to scrape this URL until the number of redirects are reduced

Tags: php, facebook, exception, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am running an FQL Query using the PHP Library. It is in an app seeing heavy use and works fine. However, with one user (A internal QA tester), it is throwing a weird FB Exception that I can't find any documentation on. The Exception message is:

"URL has too many redirects. Facebook won't be able to scrape this URL until the number of redirects are reduced."

This makes no sense given the query is:

```
$multiQuery = "info":"SELECT name, pic, sex, activities, interests, quotes, about_me, profile_blurb, music, tv, movies, books, games, sports, favorite_teams, favorite_athletes, timezone, locale, first_name FROM user WHERE uid = me()",
"likes":"SELECT user_id, object_id, object_type FROM like WHERE user_id = me() LIMIT 350",
"stream":"SELECT post_id, created_time, permalink, description, message, description_tags FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND filter_key = 'owner' AND created_time > 946684800 LIMIT 350",
"links":"SELECT link_id, created_time, owner_comment, picture FROM link WHERE owner = me() LIMIT 350",
"photos":"SELECT created, caption, src FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me() LIMIT 100) LIMIT 350",
"myPhotosLiked":"SELECT object_id, user_id FROM like WHERE object_id in (SELECT object_id FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me() LIMIT 50) LIMIT 100) LIMIT 350",
"questions":"SELECT question, created_time FROM question where owner = me() LIMIT 350"

$results = $facebook->api('fql/?q=' . urlencode($multiQuery));
// $facebook is the Facebook PHP library reference
```

Anyone run into this before?

UPDATE: Thanks all for the suggestions. Of course now the QA guy can no longer replicate. This is the second time it happened and both times it was only with his FB account (machine, browser didn't matter) and it persisted for about 24-48 hours, then just went away on its own. I will just have to wait for it to pop up again to test these suggestions.

UPDATE 2: Ok - the issue has recurred again. I had the tester try it on multiple networks and computers / devices. Same weird error every time. To clarify though, it is only happening with his FB account. If he tries any other account, it works fine.Maybe FB just has a personal beef with this guys account. Anyone had any similar type of error that was just tied to an individual account?

Comment: Is your internal tester using a proxy?

Comment: What API call is returning that error, that error isn't one i've seen in the API before, but the debug tool has such a message when you supply a URL that redirects frequently

Comment: I updated to show the API call in more detail but now the QA guy can no longer replicate (this is the second time it has cropped up). I don't think he uses a proxy but he is within a large organization with a dedicated network, etc so I told him to test it on an off-site network next time it crops up so we will see if that does anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exception thrown once. Though I was not using FQL. I went through a massive amount of crap and hacks, fixes without any joy. I just could not figure out what was causing it. Turned out that one part of my app (Second iframe for ads) was caught in a re-direct loop.

I don't know if this will help. But thought I would share anyway.

Comment: Nice share, it may not be directly applicable, but does offer a potential solution.

Comment: We have a couple redirects but they are pretty simple and occur prior to the API call but I will look at that again if the issue pops back up again. Thanks.